# is it possible to edit the cookie value

Tags: .net, cookies, web, service

I am using a cookie based authentication technique for web service authentication.
I setting a cookie value using the encryption technique in client's machine.
And that cookie value i  am using in the web service method for authentication purpose.
My doubt is, Is it possible to edit the cookie value by any of the third party extension tools in any browsers ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is indeed easy. One example is the "Edit Cookies" plugin for the Firefox browser (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/edit-cookies/).

In your scenario you are worried about plugins, hence none of the cross-site-scripting or cross-site-cooking protection mechanisms will work. These protection mechansims are only meant for web content (e.g. AJAX calls). But because plugin/extensions have more access to the client's environment they can easily interact with the cookie store.